# How to make an iOS app not be killed by iOS system in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, lifecycle

**Subtitle: How to make an iOS app launch so fast from background to foreground state?**

I just reviewed [the App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) page and make some conclusions.

Checked out the excellent apps like Apple Reminders and Spark mail, their app's launch screen just occurs in the first launch time mostly, after that, no matter how soon it's launched, the main screen will show quickly in my iPhone 6 device. (1G RAM, with lots of app installed.)

Here is my guess, the main cause is on data management when receiving memory warnings, it just releases all the retained data (array) of view controllers and other reusable objects. The app keep a low-level memory usage all the time, especially in the background state, when iOS system get the low-level usable memory to run the active app, it sends the memory warnings to all the un-active apps, especially for the background apps, if someone keeps a high-level memory usage after receiving memory warnings, iOS will try to kill it absolutely, ***or it's allowed for background apps to keep a low-level memory usage.***

If so, how many/percent used memory for iOS app is allowed? What's the threshold? Any documents for that?

I did a lot of search with no luck, please point it for me, great thanks!

Comment: Hello big brother Itachi-san! :)  There is no such thing as "how many allowed" (except from the general **app-to-hardware** in general). iOS kills your app **if it needs to** to make space for other apps. If another App needs 50% of the memory and there is no space , iOS clears out the other apps in the background as it see fits. You can not do anything about this, other than make sure your app use **as low "space" in the memory as possible** when it goes to the background. Use Instruments.

Comment: There was definitely a WWDC video that discussed the order that apps are jettisoned and they said that apps using more memory are jettisoned first. They didn't quote exact numbers, IIRC, merely saying that the more memory you app is using in its background state, the sooner it is likely to be jettisoned. I'm not finding the precise video in which this was discussed, but perhaps someone else has this at their finger tips.

Comment: Thanks! Sasuki~ It's helpful. @Sneak

Comment: So the killed sequence is ordered by used memory, I'll try to find it. Thanks! @Rob

Comment: @itachi Nowadays the hardware is really good on the iPhones/iPads etc and memory termination shouldnt be an issue in general (unless you have a heavy memory based app, games etc) The lower your memory usage is the more likely your app will not get killed by iOS. You can use the methods in the AppDelegate when your app goes to background you can "kill off" things/caches etc that you don't need in memory and put them "back in" when user comes back to your app if needed, or use the didReceiveMemory methods. Good luck

Comment: By the way, if the user uses a bunch of apps, your app may well get jettisoned. So if you want the app to start quickly, you might want to consider ways for the app to restart quickly, putting the user right where they were when they left you app. E.g., consider state restoration.